# Using .limit() with Firestore queries

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've got an application that acts as a queue using Firestore. Data comes in from another source and is stored in Firestore at `/data/{id}`, with a property `unprocessed` set to true. In my Node.js script, I'm wanting to query these unprocessed records a few at a time to process them slowly. There are hundreds of thousands of records, so attempting to load them all into memory just crashes the process.

Code:

```
firestore.collection('data').where('unprocessed', '==', true).limit(25).onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      processItem(doc);
    });
  });
```

The `processItem()` function does the necessary processing, saving the data back to Firestore with the `unprocessed` property set to false.

The problem I'm running in to is that any time I try to run this code, I get the following error:

```
Error: Error 3: Order must include __name__
    at sendError (C:\[myApp]\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\src\watch.js:254:15)
    at DestroyableTransform.stream.on.proto (C:\[myApp]\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\src\watch.js:532:13)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at addChunk (C:\[myApp]\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:284:12)
    at readableAddChunk (C:\[myApp]\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:271:11)
    at DestroyableTransform.Readable.push (C:\[myApp]\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:238:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform.push (C:\[myApp]\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:146:32)
    at afterTransform (C:\[myApp]\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:102:51)
    at TransformState.afterTransform (C:\[myApp]\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:79:12)
    at DestroyableTransform.noop [as _transform] (C:\[myApp]\node_modules\through2\through2.js:26:3)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (C:\[myApp]\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:182:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (C:\[myApp]\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:170:83)
    at doWrite (C:\[myApp]\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:406:64)
    at writeOrBuffer (C:\[myApp]\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:395:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (C:\[myApp]\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:322:11)
```

Removing the `.limit()` from my code makes it run, but then I run into another issue where the function to process and store the item back isn't finishing properly, and my memory usage just keeps growing until the process crashes.

My first instinct is to think that `.limit()` isn't compatible with `.onSnapshot()` for some reason, but perhaps someone can give me a better idea of what's going on here.

## Edit

I've also attempted to add in `.orderBy('__name__')`, as shown in https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data (in the 'delete collections' section), but this just results in yet another error:

```
Error: Trying to compare documents on fields that don't exist. Please include the fields you are ordering on in your select() call.
    at C:\[myApp]\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\src\reference.js:1679:19
    at Array.sort (native)
    at computeSnapshot (C:\[myApp]\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\src\watch.js:438:20)
    at push (C:\[myApp]\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\src\watch.js:469:18)
    at DestroyableTransform.stream.on.proto (C:\[myApp]\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\src\watch.js:514:15)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at addChunk (C:\[myApp]\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:284:12)
    at readableAddChunk (C:\[myApp]\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:271:11)
    at DestroyableTransform.Readable.push (C:\[myApp]\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:238:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform.push (C:\[myApp]\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:146:32)
    at afterTransform (C:\[myApp]\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:102:51)
    at TransformState.afterTransform (C:\[myApp]\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:79:12)
    at DestroyableTransform.noop [as _transform] (C:\[myApp]\node_modules\through2\through2.js:26:3)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (C:\[myApp]\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:182:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (C:\[myApp]\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:170:83)
```

Comment: As an experiment, add `.orderBy('unprocessed')` to your query.

Comment: @BobSnyder Adding `.orderBy('unprocessed')` results in a slightly different error: `Error: Error 3: order by clause cannot contain a field with an equality filter unprocessed`

Comment: I expected adding `.orderBy(...)` to work, based on the  [fourth example in this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `.orderBy(FirebaseFirestore.FieldPath.documentId())`, it should fix the problem. A brief explanation of why this fixes the issue is [here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/issues/59#issuecomment-342619570). Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/bmass02/01db35916db346905f682823754b8bca) of an example.

Comment: I have seen your suggested example on `gist` but I have noticed that If I add `.limit(1)` to my firestore snapshots query then Stream's listen function is not called. Kindly share your suggestion, if any. Thanks.

Comment: Not getting any error in console to do index on Firestore by following index link